# AJAX request returning "405 Method Not Allowed"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to write a submit form that sends a `JSON` object to an application on another server but I keep getting a `405 Method Not Allowed` error in the console.

The app is set up to accept `POST` and that's what I'm sending so I'm lost at where the error is. There is also a warning in the console `Loading failed for the <script> with source "Request URL"`

Is this a problem with the way the application is reading the JSON or the format the JSON is being sent in?

**From the app server**

```
Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type
```

**Code**

```
json = JSON.parse(string);
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: "jsonp",
   contentType: "application/json",
   url: "http://test:8080/request/committee",
   data: json,
   cache: false,
   success: function (response) {
       $("#successModal").modal('show');
    },
    failure: function (response) {
       $("#failureModal").modal('show');
    },
    error: function (response) {
       $("#failureModal").modal('show');
                }
    });
    e.preventDefault();//prevents the form from being submitted by default
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Host: test:8080
Referer: http://www.form.com/servlet/rsvp.jsp?location=110%20Road%20Bolton%20Landing,%20NY&purpose=%20TPAS%20Teleconference%20(RSVP%20here%20to%20attend%20in-person)&visitDate=2018-03-15&visitStartTime=6:00%20AM&visitEndDate=7:00%20AM&committee=all
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
```

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 15:38:24 GMT
```

Edit: corrected `contentType`. Same error occurs

Comment: `type: 'POST',` -> `method: 'POST'`

Comment: Try `contentType: "application/json"`. Only use JSONP for the return type, not for sending.

Comment: Why are you using jsonp? Are you having issues with cross-site requests using regular json?

Comment: @Keith, good catch.

Comment: You can't use POST request in JSONP.

Comment: @Keith [`type` is an alias for `method`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: @RacilHilan  Yeah, I did see that after looking at docs again.  The JSONP looks like the most likely issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your exception details , it seems to be 
Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type

either you are passing invalid content type or not passing at all , I see your content type is application/jsonp.
just give a try with application/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me once.  My java method wanted xml not json. this annotation (in java) fixed it for me.

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

I hope this helps!